# Is it possible to make a PCB on paper?

Tags: pcb

Is it possible to make a PCB using paper? For example since graphite conducts power, can you get a sheet of paper, and draw a circuit on it using a graphite pencil?

Comment: Welcome! Look up Pertinax PCB. It’s paper-based.

Comment: I don't know about pencil graphite, not sure of what its resistivity is.  But you could probably do something with a conductive ink.

Comment: Yes! But graphite isn't a very *good* conductor. You're basically drawing resistors.

Comment: @user253751 would making the traces "thicker" make it have less resistance?

Comment: Yes, but still too much to be sensible, probably. I bet you could blink an LED with a 555 for example, and Hackaday would accept that submission.

Comment: I'll have to take back my earlier comment.  Actually graphite/carbon is a very good conductor, though not as good as silver, copper, or gold.

Comment: There's a cheap, mostly obsolete type of PCB material called phenolic paper (also referred to as FR-2). Instead of the fiberglass and resin of typical FR-4, it uses paper and resin. It's mechanically weaker and less fire-resistant than FR-4 fiberglass, but it's cheaper, so you see it in very cheap devices.

Comment: How would you connect any components to the graphite tracks on the paper?

Comment: I remember a Forrest M Mims III design for a homemade strain/flex gage with pencil graphite on plastic, but the very thin layer of loosely-aggregated graphite on paper would not give satisfactory conductivity for a standard circuit.  Not to mention that connecting components to the traces would be difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can put together very simple circuits this way. Graphite pencils are usually a bit tricky to use for this because they don't put down much material and they're hard to make connections with.

You can buy conductive paints and inks specifically designed for this kind of "arts and crafts" style of circuit building. Circuit Scribe and Bare Conductive Paint are the two maker-friendly brands I'm most aware of, but they're sold under all sorts of other names, and both Electrolube and MG Chemicals have lines of professional quality conductive paints for PCB repair and other use-cases.

Typically you need to hold components against the ink/paint manually in order to make a good connection. You can also get conductive epoxies and glues that can help make more permanent works.

The resistance of the painted/drawn traces will be quite high, and the parasitic properties (capacitance and inductance) will be poor, so you'll be somewhat limited in terms of the types of circuits you could build this way, but for simple things like powering LEDs and demoing basic transistor circuits it's perfectly workable. I know a few people who have done workshops for kids with stuff like this and it's pretty fun.

Answer (score 3):

Oh yes!

A guy at university perfected this method for hobby use.

He has hacked a common ink-jet printer to use refilled cartridges with conductive paint. He got a really old printer, which doesn't "bend" the paper - this allowed to feed through even thicker materials (like 1mm plastic foil or what not.)

I don't know much about resolution or repeatability, but I guess it is quite useable in the .3mm track/pad size/spacing domain - at least from what I saw.

He used it for all kinds of stuff. I have even seen some 64QFN/TQFN - 0603 footprints fabricated this way.

To "solder" stuff he would let the finished circuit dry and then applied alcohol to the pads in question. They got "wet" again and he simply pressed down the component and let it cure. The ink formed not only an electrical but also a mechanical connection.

I imagine this method also beeing able to print at least double layer - how to get the alignment correct, or how to fabricate the vias is another question.

He dropped his work on the device as he discovered the univeristy PCB service.
It is free to use for students (in reasonable boundaries,) fast and has some very impressive design rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done, use the blackest pencil you can find, because the blacker the pencil the more pure the graphite is.

search for `draw circuit with pencil` for several examples.

I'm not claiming that this is practical, but it can be done.